# Error 6248: Crystal SAP Merge Module...?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, installshield

I am trying to create a Setup Routine for my application which uses Crystal Reports SAP. I get 4 errors durring the build stating that the following files are missing:

- 6248: Could not find dependent file CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
- 6248: Could not find dependent file CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll
- 6248: Could not find dependent file CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll
- 6248: Could not find dependent file CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.dll

I've downloaded the [CRforVS2010_sp1_mm.zip] directly from Business Objects and copied the [CRRuntime_13_0_1.msm] file into my [C:\Program Files\InstallShield\2011\Modules\i386] directory. I restarted the installer and then I selected the [SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .Net Framework 4] in the [Redistributables] tab. I don't know what else I need to do.

I am running the following:

- Visual Studio 2010 (VB.Net)
- InstallShield Express 2011

Help!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like an answer is [Here](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?t=198638) and [Here](http://community.installshield.com/showpost.php?p=471093&postcount=7)

> old version of the MS VC++ SP1 Redistributable Prerequisite file.